# Download file with special character ":" from AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have some trouble with downloading the above file from aws.
I tried to download this file by CouldBerry Explore and Java, but I failed.
The aws document says that I need require special handling.(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)
So, could you tell me how to handle downloading this file with ":"?

The following is my file infomation.

File name:"E:\Home\temp\test-1_20180101.csv"

Object key:"testaws/data/E:\Home\temp\test-1_20180101.csv"

When I tried to download file by CouldBerry Explore, the ettro message is "The request Signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

And I show you Java codes to download file

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

...
String prefix ="testaws/data/"
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(MY_BUCKET_NAME).withPrefix(prefix).withDelimiter("/");
ObjectListing list = s3.listObjects(request);
List<S3ObjectSummary> summary = list.getObjectSummaries();
...
```

summary contains nothing, so it seems to fail to downloading file.
(Obviously, I successfully download file without ":"）

Comment: If you don't see the file in an object listing, it's likely not uploaded in the first place. Also note that the page you link clearly says that you should *avoid* backslashes in a key name.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on a Mac and successfully managed to upload/download a file with that name. However, I had to **quote the name** so that the backslashes were not interpreted as escape characters:

```
aws s3 cp "s3://my-bucket/testaws/data/E:\Home\temp\test-1_20180101.csv" test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I can download the windows version. I'll try that.